# How to set aws-sdk credentials using Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm running an express app in Elastic Beanstalk and in one route I'm using the aws-sdk to publish a notification to sns.

This works when running locally, but in the Elastic Beanstalk environment how would/could I set up the credentials 'myprofile'?

```
router.post('/publish', async (req, res) => {
  var AWS = require('aws-sdk')
  AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-2'})
  // myprofile exists locally, but how do I deal with this in the elastic beanstalk environment?
  var credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({profile: 'myprofile'})
  AWS.config.credentials = credentials
  //...more stuff
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use IAM instance profile to provide permissions to your ec2 instance, so when your application loads the SDK, the credentials passed will be automatically loaded.

Check this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts-roles.html - what you will need is the instance profile. In order to create a instance profile go to the IAM console > Roles, then choose the service EC2 as a service that can assume this role. Then attach the policies that your application needs calling (SNS stuff).

On the beanstalk settings, under security, you will be able to set the IAM instance profile that you just created - so the instances on this environment should have the role associated with it.

Your code should look like then:

```
router.post('/publish', async (req, res) => {
  var AWS = require('aws-sdk')
  AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-2'})

  //...more stuff
})
```

Also check if you can require and set the region outside of the controller ;)

Comment: thanks for the info! I'm confused though, locally I need to specify the profile (I have several set up so i need to specifiy which one), how do i deal with this? there will be error in eb since it will not find 'myprofile' credentials

Comment: Np. The point is that the instance profile will be an alternative to the profile. If you need exactly the same permissions present on 'myprofile', just attach the same policies to the instance profile.